# Highcharts SVG element not updating. Custom Freeform Drawing inside Highchats?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, highcharts

I am using highchart for rendering graphs and also using the renderer in order to draw a custom line inside the chart. I want this path to be recalculated and repainted whenever there is a data change. I am using highcharts-ng and angular for the same. The code is mentioned below:-

```
{
            options: {
                chart: {
                    type: 'line',
                    marginTop: 80,
                    style: {
                        fontFamily: 'serif',
                        fontSize:14
                    },
                    events:{
                        redraw:function(e){
                            console.log(e)
                            var elem=e.target.renderer.Element()
                            console.log(elem)
                            console.log('I am Reloaded')
                        }
                    }
                    //backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)'
                },
                exporting: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        animation: false,
                        marker: {
                            symbol: 'circle'
                        },
                        lineWidth: 1,
                        events: {
                            afterAnimate: function () {
                                console.log('lol')
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                colors: ['#2C91DE', '#165A8E'],
            },
            tooltip: {
                style: {
                    padding: 10,
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: ""
            },
            loading: false,
            series: [],
            func: (chart) => {
                this.$timeout(() => {
                    console.log(chart)
                    var ren = chart.renderer;
                    var group = ren.g().add();
                    var attrForVLine = {
                        'stroke-width': 3,
                        stroke: '#2C91DE',
                        dashstyle: 'solid'
                    };

                    for (var i = 0; i < chart.series[0].data.length; i++) {
                        var plot1 = chart.series[0].data[i];
                        var plot2 = chart.series[1].data[i];

                        /**
                         * Creating line segments across the graphs.
                         * Keeping the ZIndex low for these lines.
                         */
                        ren.path([
                            'M',
                            plot1.plotX + chart.plotLeft,
                            plot1.plotY + chart.plotTop,
                            'V',
                            plot2.plotY + chart.plotTop
                        ]).attr(attrForVLine).add();
                    }
                }, 1000);
            },
            yAxis: {
                tickInterval: 40,
                title: {
                    text: ''
                }
            },
            xAxis: {
                startOnTick: true,
                endOnTick: true,
                lineColor: '#000000',
                type: 'datetime',
                labels: {
                    rotation: -60,
                    format: '{value:%m-%d-%Y}',
                    align: 'right'
                }
            }
        };
```

Whenever this chart is rendered it also renders a path. But if the data changes the path does not change rather it remains the same. Please help. I want to update the SVG rendered dynamically. Thanks

Chart mentioned below has vertical lines drawn by renderer
[image]

When I change the Data the lines drawn by renderer needs to be removed but it still stays and the graph is repainted with different data points.As shown below
[image]

I want to get rid of these lines and redraw them.

Comment: Are you able to show us live example of your issue?

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński actually its here in my official Project. I can share the screen shot though. I have added it up.

Comment: You should be able to save your paths as an object in your chart and update them on every redraw. Look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/vwuscjdv/1/

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe late, but those SVGs are implemented as an overlay SVG on top of chart's SVG. So when the chart changes, they don't change because they are independent. You have to manually delete previous SVGs and draw them again. You could listen to the "render" event of chart and call a function to redraw your SVGs. Take a look at the ollowing example:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    events: {
      render: function() {
        const points = [{
            x: 0.1,
            y: 0.1
          },
          {
            x: 0.2,
            y: 0.4
          },
          {
            x: 0.3,
            y: 0.9
          }
        ];
        const path = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
          i === 0 ? path.push("M") : path.push("L");
          path.push(this.xAxis[0].toPixels(points[i].x));
          path.push(this.yAxis[0].toPixels(points[i].y));
        }
         if (this.customPath) {
          this.customPath.destroy()
          this.customPath = undefined
        }
        this.customPath = this.renderer.g('customPath').add()
        
        this.renderer.path(path)
          .attr({
            stroke: 'green',
            'stroke-width': 1,
            zIndex: 1
          })
          .add(this.customPath);
      }
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    lineWidth: 1,
    min: 0,
    max: 1,
    minorTicks: true
  },

  yAxis: {
    lineWidth: 1,
    min: 0,
    max: 1,
    minorTicks: true
  },

  legend: {
    enabled: true
  },

  series: [{ id: "dummy" }]

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

JSFiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/reza_karimi76/7tpz1fea)